# IRSSI: HilightWin is showing Joins/Parts/Quits

Tags: irssi

`Hilightwin.pl` is showing Joins/Parts/Quits from all my channels. I would assume that it is an issue that involves levels, except I have no idea where to start.

Some plugins that I use that might be relevant:

- Crapbuster.pl
- HilightWin.pl
- Highlite.pl

#### .irssi/config

```
aliases = {
...
  CB = "crapbuster";
  CBALL = "foreach window /crapbuster";
};

settings = {
...
  "perl/core/scripts" = {
    awl_display_key = "$Q|%n$H$C$S";
    awl_block = "15";
    crapbuster_levels = "JOINS PARTS QUITS NICKS CLIENTCRAP CRAP MODE TOPICS KICKS";
  };
};
hilights = { text = "NICKNAME"; nick = "yes"; word = "yes"; };
logs = { };
windows = {
  9 = { name = "hilight"; sticky = "yes"; };
};
mainwindows = {
  1 = { first_line = "5"; lines = "16"; };
  9 = { first_line = "1"; lines = "4"; };
};
ignores = (
  { level = "JOINS PARTS QUITS NICKS"; channels = ( "#highlite" ); }
);
```

Comment: Did you found an answer ? As I have the same problem and don't find anything on Google...